# What's the best way to phrase "没事是......做什么?" in english?

Tags: translation, phrase

I found that that form of phrase is used quite often.
I thought it could be read as "What are you being .... for?".
But I'm still confused about the use of '没事' here and how to properly put it in English.

Comment: Can you give some examples on the structure  “没事是…做什?"? I can't get any in mind.

Comment: 没事说那么恶心的话做什么? It seems 是 isn't a fixed part in the structure....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean “没事…做什?" If it is the case, then  没事 is short for '**没事要做** (without thing that has to be done); or **没事發生**(nothing has happened)

> 没事 means '**for no reason**' or '**with no purpose**' in this structure.

For example:

"**没事**回來做什?" (**for no reason**, come back **for what**?/ **why** come back **for no reason**?)

"**没事**去看醫生做什?" (**for no reason**, go to see the doctor **for what**?/ **why** go see the doctor **for no reason**?)

> *It should be' 没事...作什', but '没事...做什?' is also valid because 做 is the modern counterpart of 作 in classical writting for the verb 'to do'*

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's a bit akin to, the good old:

> the devil will find work for idle hands to do

**没事** here means exactly what you probably think it means.

[MDBG](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqb=%E6%B2%A1%E4%BA%8B) lists one definition as:

> to have nothing to do

In your above question the 没事 basically acts as, '*don't you have anything better to do than to....*', '*are you so idle as to...*', etc. -or- as you put it *What are you being .... for?*

Answer (score 0):

'没事‘ = 'everything is ok' is this case.
‘做什么’ equates to 'why' here I think.

没事说那么恶心的话做什么?
Everything is fine, why are you uttering such profanities?